# Python - Interpolating between lines of data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have data on a 2d grid characterized by points (x,Y,Z).  The X and Y values indicate each point's position and Z is "height" or "intensity" at each point.

My issue is that my data coordinates along the X axis are extremely closely spaced (~1000 points), while my Y coordinates are spread out (~50 points).  This means that when plotted on a scatter plot, I essentially have lines of data with an equal amount of blank space between neighboring lines.

*Example of how my data is spaced on a scatter plot:*

```
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo


ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo


ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

I want to interpolate these points to get a continuous surface.  I want to be able to evaluate the "height" at any position on this surface.  I have tried what seems like every scipy interpolation method and am not sure of what the most "intelligent" method is.  Should I interpolate each vertical slice of data, then stitch them together?

I want as smooth a surface as possible, but need a shape preserving method.  I do not want any of the interpolated surface to overshoot my input data.

Any help you can provide would be very helpful.

**EDIT:**

As I think about the problem more, it seems that interpolating the vertical slices and then stitching them together wouldn't work.  That would cause the value along a vertical slice to only be effected by that slice, Wouldn't that result in an inaccurate surface?

Comment: What do you mean by 'overshoot'?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend this  [tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#multivariate-data-interpolation-griddata).   The guts of it are (lifted from link):

```
>>> grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:200j]
>>> from scipy.interpolate import griddata
>>> grid_z0 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')
>>> grid_z1 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')
>>> grid_z2 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
```

Which will get you three different levels of interpolation of your data [(doc)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  This is actually one of the many methods I am implementing already.  Cubic is out of the questions since it overshoots the input data.  Linear interpolation doesn't seem to fit very well, but it is an option.

Comment: Did you also look at the spline fitting further down that page?  I have found the 1D splines to work very well for noisy data.  Can you smooth your data at all (that will help with the over-shooting which is caused by fluctuations in the 2nd derivative of the data).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the surface, my assumption would be that you can get by using vertical slices, and then plotting the filled out data.